# bash удаление старых файлов в дирректории с сохранением последних X файлов

Tags: linux, bash, резервное-копирование, find

Необходимо удалить старые бэкапы из указанной дирректории, которые старше 5 дней. При условии, что после удаления, в дирректории останется не меньше X файлов.
Если файлов останется меньше, то не удалять.

Краткое описание ситуации:
Иногда сервер выключен, поэтому бэкапы делаются не постоянно. Сервер запускают через неделю  и скрипт удаляет все бэкапы. А надо бы сохранить последние X файлов, и не важно, что они старше 5 дней.

Раньше было реализовано через find

```
find /path -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

Но это не решает проблему, описанную выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К ответу @Oopss

```
ls -t ./* | tail -n +3 | xargs rm
```

`ls -t` - вывести отсортировав по времени

```
$ ls -t
10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

`tail -n +3` - хвост списка начиная с 3его сначала, чтоб оставить 5 - пиши `+6`

```
$ ls -t | tail -n +3
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

`xargs rm` - передает список команде rm

Comment: Да, без промежуточных файлов гораздо лучше, и переменная str у меня тоже не нужна, вставил только чтобы показать последовательные шаги.

Comment: Ну тут тоже шаги показал